# how to for loop a jq array result in shell script

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have a json data as below

```
{
  "id": {
    "bioguide": "E000295",
    "thomas": "02283",
    "govtrack": 412667,
    "opensecrets": "N00035483",
    "lis": "S376"
  },
  "bio": {
    "gender": "F",
    "birthday": "1970-07-01"
  },
  "tooldatareports": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "tooldata": [
        {
          "toolid": 12345,
          "data": [
            {
              "time": "2021-01-01",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-02",
              "value": 10
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-03",
              "value": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "toolid": 12346,
          "data": [
            {
              "time": "2021-01-01",
              "value": 10
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-02",
              "value": 100
            },
            {
              "time": "2021-01-03",
              "value": 50
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

now I can use below command line to get a list containing two dict,
each dict have a key "data", value is a list,

```
cat data.json |jq -n --stream '[fromstream(inputs | (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix:])]'
```

I want to print each dict with a loop in shell script

My except in each loop have printed a dict, total have 2 dict

But it seems like a string

below is my shell script

```
array=$(cat ernst.json | jq -n --stream '[fromstream(inputs | (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix:])]')

for d in $array
do
    echo $d
done
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ jq -cn --stream '[fromstream(inputs | (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix:])][]' data.json | while read d; do echo "item: $d"; done
item: {"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":1},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":5}]}
item: {"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":100},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":50}]}
```

Note that you can get very similar output with simpler `jq`:

```
jq -c '.tooldatareports[].tooldata[].data' data.json  | while read d; do echo "item: $d"; done
item: [{"time":"2021-01-01","value":1},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":5}]
item: [{"time":"2021-01-01","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":100},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":50}]
```

And you can get identical output (this seems likely to be unnecessary) with:

```
$ jq -c '.tooldatareports[].tooldata[].data | {"data": .}' data.json  | while read d; do echo "item: $d"; done
item: {"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":1},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":5}]}
item: {"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":100},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":50}]}
```

Comment: nice method, but I need to use --stream flag because my final target file is huge

Answer (score 2):

Your output is a json list, so you won't get away with a direct bash loop over it. The bash loop won't know what to do with the square brackets and will use each space and newline as a separator. Use `jq` again to get separate objects from your json list. That is done with `jq -c '.[]'`:

```
array=$(cat data.json |jq -n --stream '[fromstream(inputs | (.[0] | index("data")) as $ix | select($ix) | .[0] |= .[$ix:])]' | jq -c '.[]')
```

Now you have two objects in two separate lines and no spaces (`-c` = compact output) and you can loop over them in bash:

```
for d in $array
do
    echo "$d"
    # whatever else you need to do with them
done

{"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":1},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":5}]}
{"data":[{"time":"2021-01-01","value":10},{"time":"2021-01-02","value":100},{"time":"2021-01-03","value":50}]}
```

Comment: You did two calls to `jq`. Can it be done with a single call ?

Comment: @Philippe yes, you can just add `-c` and `[]` to the first `jq` invocation. I don't always prefer the most compact solution though. I often prefer a clear separation of concerns instead. That is what pipelines are great for. In this case, I thought it was more important to show the OP what each step does.

Comment: very clear to explain the bash loop, thanks